# Depending on the var name the method outputs something in Java

Tags: java

I wrote a method to print my results. Can I modify the method to print a different message if the parameter is called let's say '**result3**' ?

In this case below, I can't acess the variable **result2** inside the method. Eclipse say "'result2' cannot be resolved to a variable".

```
        double result2 = addValues(s1,s2,s3);
        printAnswer(result2);

    }

    static void printAnswer (double answer) {
        System.out.println("The answer is:" + " " + answer);
    }
```

Do I need to modify 'printAnswer' to a non static method?

Comment: Correct, inside the method the variable is named `answer`.

Comment: `printAnswer` doesn't know the name of the variable you used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of the variable passed to the method as a parameter is not known to the method. Moreover, there may be more than one variable involved

```
printAnswer(result2+result3);
```

or no variables at all

```
printAnswer(42.53);
```

making the question "what was the name of the variable passed to my method?" impossible to answer.

Your method can act only on the value of the `answer` parameter, not on the argument expression used to call your method.

If you want to differentiate on something in addition to the value, have your caller pass you an additional argument, like this:

```
static void printAnswer (double answer, String name) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot, and should not condition output based on variable names, ONLY use conditions based on variable VALUES

like this:

```
static void printAnswer (double answer) {
    if(answer>0){
          System.out.println("The answer is positive: " + answer);
     }else{
          System.out.println("The answer is negative or cero: " + answer);
     }
}
```

EDIT:

if you want to write the sum method so it takes an unknown amount of values to sum, then you wirte it like this:

```
 public static double addValues(Double... values){
    double sum=0;
    for(Double value:values){
        sum+=value.doubleValue();
    }
    return sum;
}
```

this way you can know the amount of parameters accessing those parameters as you would with any array:

```
values.length
```

and call it with any amount of parameters

```
addValues(1.5,1.6,5.9,2.3);
```

Comment: It's because I want something that if a call a method addValues(s1,s2) it outputs something different then when I call method addValues(s1,s2,s3) and so on..

Comment: i edited the answer to include what i think you are looking for.